# Does erasing a shared_ptr from a set deletes the managed object

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, move-semantics

In the following code, I expect the memory that pointer `tr` points, to be destroyed. However even though I verified `sp1`, points to the same address with `tr`, and clearing the set causes the `trial` object `sp` kept to be destroyed, `tr` still points to the same address and the `trial` object it shows is not destroyed, according to gdb, at the line `return 0`.

```
class trial
:public enable_shared_from_this<trial>
{
public:
    trial(int n)
    {
        cout<<"new trial created with number : " << n << endl;
        a = (int*)malloc(4);
        *a = n;
    }


    ~trial() {
        cout << "trial destroyed"<< endl;
    }

    int *a;
};

int main() {
    cout << "Program Started" << endl;

    trial *tr = new trial(5);
    shared_ptr<trial> sp1(tr);
    set<shared_ptr<trial>> trialVector;

    trialVector.insert(std::move(sp1));


    trialVector.clear();

    return 0;
}
```

When the program arrives to the line of `return 0`, console shows this :

```
Program Started
new trial created with number : 5
trial destroyed
```

acknowledging that, tr is indeed destroyed, once sp1 is removed from the set. But tr has still the same address and the same value.

What is going on here?

**Edit:** For clarity, my question is this:

Shouldn't the content of the address the pointer `tr` shows should be erased, once the last shared_ptr pointing to the manager object which points to the adress of pointer `tr` , is destructed upon being erased from the set ?

Comment: I don't understand what is the question exactly? it's seems ok.

Comment: How can you determine that the "object is not destroyed"? After the destructor ran, inspecting the guts of what's left at that memory address is essentially meaningless - the object is dead.

Comment: Because in the debugger, I can see that it shows the same address, and that address has still the same trial object with value 5 for a, in it.

Comment: `tr` is now a dangling pointer - as soon as you pass control over to a `shared_ptr` it's risky to rely on the original raw pointer remaining valid as the `shared_ptr` is now responsible for its lifetime. In short, it's undefined behaviour to dereference `tr` once the `shared_ptr` has been destroyed.

Comment: That is exactly the point of my experiment. It is undefined but how? `tr` still indeed has the same trial object after all shared_ptr is destroyed, and the managed object is destroyed.

Comment: Meaning that if I add line `cout << *(tr->a);` before the line `return 0;` , it will print out 5. I was suspicios that the address changes once a shared_ptr is created with a pointer, but that is not the case. When sp1 is created, it points to the managed_object which points to the same address with pointer `tr`.

Comment: Undefined, meaning the C++ standard doesn't define what happens when you access unallocated memory. Anything can happen, including it still looking like a valid object.

Comment: @OzumSafa [this analogy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/3422652) might help

Comment: Why are you using malloc?

Comment: No particular reason, just happened to do that there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the object is destroyed `tr` becomes a dangling pointer or the pointer to released memory. Why would the value in `tr` change if it is just a separate variable which happens to hold address to some point in memory?

Comment: The value that the address has is not changed. Of course tr is going to show the same address, but that address still has the same `trial` object in it. According to gdb, paused at line `return 0`, it is.

Comment: Deallocation does not mean that the memory somewhere is wiped out, the object of class `trial` is still there, but the OS has marked the memory as free. If You were to create a `new trial` now, probably malloc would choose this spot for allocation, and the content of memory would change.
This is why You always have to init a variable, as simply allocating it will make the variable hold data perviously in memory.
As to why gdb can access this memory location, this spot, even when marked as free, still belongs to Your application.

Comment: I hear you. That actually was great info. I think i figured out my confusion after i removed inheritence of `public enable_shared_from_this<trial>`. Once i did that, there was still trial object in the memory, but the integer pointer as nullified. That was the reaction i was expecting. Because deleting an integer pointer, makes the value 0, back to default. Now that I deleted the memory point to a trial object, it acted, probably in an undefined way, getting memory back to a default trial object state.

Answer (score 0):

If you try following debug code it will be evident that `shared_ptr` sp1 has reference count is zero after `std::vector::clear()` call.

```
trialVector.clear();
std::cout<<sp1.use_count();
```